# "Method Not Allowed" error in Flask after submitting form data

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, forms, flask

After clicking on Submit in my form I am getting "Method Not Allowed
The method is not allowed for the requested URL."

The required code is below

**hello.py**

```
@app.route('/')
def home():
    return render_template("home.html")

@app.route('/register', methods=["GET", "POST"])
def register():
    
    
    if request.method == "POST":
#        data = {}
        name = request.form['name']
        place = request.form['place']
        descr = request.form['descr']
        email = request.form['email']
        collection.insert_one({'name': name, 'place': place, 'email': email, 'descr': descr})
           
    return render_template("register.html")
```

**register.html**

```
<form action="." method="post">
                      
            <h1> COMPLAINT FORM </h1>
                              
            <input class="box" type="text" name="name" id="name" 
            placeholder="Name"  required /><br>

            <input class="box" type="place" name="place" id="place" 
            placeholder="Place" required /><br>
                              
            <input class="box" type="email" name="email" id="email" 
            placeholder="E-Mail " required /><br>

            <input class="box" type="text" name="descr" id="descr" 
            placeholder="Enter Description " required /><br>
                          
            <input type="submit" id="submitDetails"  
            name="submitDetails" value="Submit" /><br>
                      
            </form>
```

I also tried including a redirect link in *form action="."* but it throws the same error.

Comment: what do you aim by giving the `action = "."`? do you want to go back to the home end point ?

Comment: Yes, I could redirect it to any page but I don't think this is causing the issue I am facing.

Comment: Actually I think this is where you have the problem, the redirection should be like this `action = "/"`. and you need to allow the post method in the `home` as well

Comment: You're welcome, please upvote the answer and accept it :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the way you want to redirect from the `/register` endpoint to the home. You want to post something to the home so the code should be as follows:

**hello.py**

```py
@app.route('/', methods=["GET", "POST"])
def home():
    return render_template("home.html")

@app.route('/register', methods=["GET", "POST"])
def register():
    
    
    if request.method == "POST":
#        data = {}
        name = request.form['name']
        place = request.form['place']
        descr = request.form['descr']
        email = request.form['email']
        collection.insert_one({'name': name, 'place': place, 'email': email, 'descr': descr})
           
    
    return render_template("register.html")
```

**register.html**

```html
<form action="/" method="post">
                      
            <h1> COMPLAINT FORM </h1>
                              
            <input class="box" type="text" name="name" id="name" 
            placeholder="Name"  required /><br>

            <input class="box" type="place" name="place" id="place" 
            placeholder="Place" required /><br>
                              
            <input class="box" type="email" name="email" id="email" 
            placeholder="E-Mail " required /><br>

            <input class="box" type="text" name="descr" id="descr" 
            placeholder="Enter Description " required /><br>
                          
            <input type="submit" id="submitDetails"  
            name="submitDetails" value="Submit" /><br>
                      
            </form>
```